# How to implement one to many relationship between interfaces in c#?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I want to define 2 interfaces for Bank(IBank) and Account(IAccount). I'm not sure, should I put a list of `IAccount` into `IBank` interface or a property of type `IBank` in `IAccount`?

My main entity according to the needs of software is `IAccount` and I just want `IBank` to find extra information about each account.

here is my primary implementation :

```
public interface IBank
    {
        int BankId { get; }
        string Name { get; }
        string Description { get; }
        string BranchCode { get; }
        DateTime CreatedAt { get; }
        DateTime ModifiedAt { get; }
        List<IAccount> Accounts { get; }
    }

public interface IAccount
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        DateTime Created { get; set; }
        string AccountNumber { get; set; }                
        int BankId { get; set; }
        decimal Value { get; }        
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think you _need_ to express this relationship using instance properties? And why using interfaces?

Comment: I don't know. what is the best approach with SOLID in mind ? I want to use EF Code first in future so I guess to put relationship in interface. @Dai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the business relationship that IBank and IAccount should represent.

So I assume that;

- A bank can have 0, 1, or more bank accounts.
- A bank account can only be linked to a single bank.

So then we can have the following

```
public class BankAccount:  IAccount
{
   //other properties
   public IBank AssociatedBank {get; set;}
}

public class Bank:  IBank
{
    //other properties
    public List<IAccount>  BankAccounts { get; set; } = new List<BankAccount>();
}
```

This way we have the business relationship we want to represent.  Each `BankAccount` is of type `IAccount` and is linked to a single `AssociatedBank`, which is of type `IBank`.
Each Bank is of type `IBank` and has 0,1, or more `BankAccounts` of type `IAccount`.

What you need to consider, is do you really need to associate them in both directions?
From what you have described, maybe you don't need to have a link from Banks to the accounts and a "one-way" link from BankAccount to a Bank is sufficient.

Your data model should only represent what is really needed in your system, everything else is over-specified.  It is tempting to do more, but very important to stick to the specification.

Edit:
If this is the case, then you can remove `public List<IAccount>  BankAccounts { get; set; } ...` from your Bank class.

Comment: Hi Jason, So Should I remove ` List<IAccount> Accounts { get; }` from `IBank` interface and also remove `int BankId { get; set; }` from `IAccount` interface ?(and only place the needed relationship in class definition?) @jason.kaisersmith

Comment: @HabilHarati Yes.  I updated the answer accordingly.